# how to get the config file path of redis through a ps command

Tags: redis, centos, ps

when i typed the `ps -ef | grep redis` and tried to find the config file path which redis process is currently using. But get a result like:

```
root ... pid ... ./redis-server 0.0.0.0:6379
```

it didn't show the full startup arguments.
the expect result should be something like:

```
root ... pid ... ./redis-server /etc/redis/redis.conf
```

so, is there any way i can find the /path/to/config but not using redis-cli info?

btw, `cat /proc/{$pid}/cmdline` shows the same result as `ps` command. OS: centos

Comment: What about using `lsof` or the `INFO` command?

Comment: tried, the `lsof -p` didn't show config path, i think that's because the config file is already loaded and redis-server process ain't current keep the configfile open any more.

Comment: Was just a guess. `INFO` does have the details if you can connect.